# Why is /storage/sdcard0/Music returned as the Qt standard music path, but /mnt/sdcard/Music is the path that works to show and play my mp3s?

Tags: android, qt

QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::MusicLocation) returns `/storage/sdcard0/Music/` on my Android devices (both older 4.1.2 and latest 5.1.1), but my mp3s are actually all located in `/mnt/sdcard/Music/`

I can easily fix this by simply replacing `/storage/sdcard0/` with `/mnt/sdcard/`, but I don't think that is very future proof or correct.

Is `/mnt/sdcard/` the correct path to use (I have tried all other variants I can come up with and none work with *QML MediaPlayer*) and why is Qt standard paths returning `/storage/sdcard0/` which is clearly not working on any device I own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those paths are actually the same path. The `/mnt` folder has references to locations on the device.

Since `/mnt` is an Android standard now, using that would be your best bet.

Comment: Interesting then that the /mnt/sdcard/ path works with QML MediaPlayer, but /storage/sdcard0/ does not.

Comment: It is possible that the QML MediaPlayer has some sort of permissions issue, like it's trying to access /storage directly then getting the sdcard0 folder. I don't know what the exact implementation is though.